# programmatically create new table with ios-core data

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, core-data

Can Core Data allow me to create new table programmatically? or if I need that I need to use SQLite directly.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a CoreData perspective, you don't really create new tables because database tables are only one possible type of persistence store associated with the core data model.

You can, however, create new core data entities programatically using the NSEntityDescription class. In the NSEntityDescription class documentation you will find this:

```
Entity descriptions are editable until they are used by an object graph manager. This
allows you to create or modify them dynamically. However, once a description is used 
(when the managed object model to which it belongs is associated with a persistent store
coordinator), it must not (indeed cannot) be changed. This is enforced at runtime: any
attempt to mutate a model or any of its sub-objects after the model is associated with a 
persistent store coordinator causes an exception to be thrown. If you need to modify a
model that is in use, create a copy, modify the copy, and then discard the objects with
the old model.
```

I've never tried to modify one at runtime, so I'm not sure exactly how well this works when you have an existing SQLite persistence store, if at all. But it's probably worth playing around with NSEntityDescription to see if it gets you close to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Tim, as compare to many of the iOS frameworks, coredata is a bit hectic for me to get used to.

Comment: @shebelaw: It is pretty complex to start off with, but if you need a booster, I'd recommend the Big Nerd Ranch books. They put things in layman terms, they don't beat around the bush either. http://www.bignerdranch.com/books it's probably cheaper to get the books on Amazon as second hand copies, but still worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You typically create the managed object model graphically using Xcode's Data Model Design tool. (If you wish you can construct the model programmatically at runtime

[Core Data programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-207332-TPXREF151)

Comment: I don't think that is possible. where you able to do this before?

Comment: @Shanmugaraja G: You can't programatically change models once they've been pulled in through the persistent store. You can however change models which aren't 'locked' by a store.

Answer (score 0):

You can however:

- Create a Object Model Context (outside of the current one you are in/using)
- Create one or more Entities
- Create a SEPARATE persistent store for that model
- Save entities etc...
- Close the store when you're done

You can't change models on the fly as they are pretty much fixed when they're pulled into the runtime environment.